# strange result with operators precedence in C

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I just have simple question, I am aware of C language, A while ago i came across this piece of code:

```
int a;
a=12/8*8;
```

I tried it using codeblocks and result was that a=8 !!!!!
How did the compiler deal with that?

Thanks.

Comment: The compiler doesn't cancel out terms as a human would; the multiplication and division operators are evaluated from left to right, so you get `(12 / 8) * 8`, where `12 / 8` is an integer division that yields an integer, hence the fractional parts are lost. This can actually be useful in code where you want to round down to the next multiple of 8. If you want a closer result, do the multiplication first (but be aware of overflow) and divide then: `12 * 8 / 8`.

Comment: @MOehm: Actually a human also could not simly eliminate the `8`s, because these are not real values, but integral numbers. There are specific rules how to calculate with such values in general; the programming language just follows these rules. Basically, this is `a = roundtozero(12 / 8) * 8`.

Comment: @Olaf: Well, I have written that under the impression that the OP was surprised that dividing by 8 and then multiplying again didn't yield the original result. The "cancelling out" refers to what you do visually when seeing such a formula. When I see 12/8 written down somewhere, I think: that's 1.5; I certainly don't think: oh, 12 and 8 are integers, so this is truncating division.

Comment: @MOehm: It depends on the context. If I know it is integral arithmetics, you actually have to. As I wrote, the division is actually argument to some rounding function, so there are very well (kinda) parentheses involved. Maybe you work more with floats, though. I work almost completely with integers.

Comment: @Olaf: I was thinkig outside the context of computers. It is a common problem for beginners here that they expect `12/8` be a real division, because that's usually how you would see in in, e.g. a maths problem. Once you know that there are two kinds of division, you get aware of such things, of course. Maybe the "cancelling out" wording was more confusing than enlightening.

Comment: @MOehm: Not sure. I learned at school to always check which number system to use. A division of two natural numbers yields a quotient and a remainder. And this is one of the first things a beginner should (re)learn for programming. But I might be too long a time working with integers to be representative:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to operator precedence ( * and / have same precedence) and associativity (they have left to right associativity)

```
12/8*8 is equal to (12/8)*8
```

Due to integer division

```
(12/8)*8 is equal to (1)*8
```

Hence, the final value is `8`.

Answer (score 4):

The multiplication operator and division operator have the same precedence level, and are evaluated from left to right.  So the above is equivalent to:

```
a=(12/8)*8;
```

The division is integer division, so the result is `1` since the fractional part gets truncated.  That is then multiplied by `8`, resulting in `8` being assigned to `a`.